# PDF.js Setting a field value?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, pdf, pdf.js

I hope you're all doing well. So I've been working with PDF.js by Mozilla for a while now. We're using it to display PDF forms to be filled out on a mobile app. Everything works great, I'm just trying to implement a feature where you can cache the users entries so that they can resume from where they left off. For a few reasons I can't just download the PDF to save it and then load it back up when they wat to resume.

Essentially I want to store all the user entries and the Field ID for each of them, which I've already gotten working, and then when the user wants to resume I want it to load the empty PDF, and then automatically re-populate all the fields with the cached entries.

I know I could set the individual text fields, but when I do that it doesn't apply to the annotationStorage so when I parse the form, those fields are read as blank.

I've tried the following lines of code in an attempt to set a field value with the id "5R"

```
PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue('5R', "Shirboogle");
```

```
PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.annotationStorage.getAll()['5R'].value = "Shirboogle";
```

```
var objs = await PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.getFieldObjects();
objs['Address 1 Text Box'][0].value = "Shirboogle";
// and
objs['Address 1 Text Box'][0].defaultValue = "Shirboogle";
```

```
// This will actually set the value of the text field, but when I look for it in annotationStorage OR
// getFieldObjects() the value is still unchanged.
document.getElementById('pdfjs_internal_id_5R').value = 'Shapoopsies';
```

along with many other attempts. I've looked all over and nothing seems to be available, so if you have any ideas please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

- In case anyone is having trouble with this, here is the solution I came up with. It seems to work great for my use case but may not be sufficient for every case. I figured I'd at least share what I got to work.
- It basically sets everything manually. There are still some UI elements I need to make an if statement for to set, but anyways. Here's my code. Good luck :)

---

```
function getFieldValue(id) {
    return PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.annotationStorage.getAll()[id].value;
}


async function getFieldObjById(id) {
    var objs = await PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.getFieldObjects();
    for(var i=0; i<Object.values(objs).length; i++) {
        if(Object.values(objs)[i][0].id == id) {
            return Object.values(objs)[i][0];
        }
    }
}

async function setFieldValue(id, val) {
    var fElementId = "pdfjs_internal_id_" + id;
    var fObject = await getFieldObjById(id);
    var objType = fObject.type;
    
    // Depending on the element type we set the value accordingly.
    if(objType == 'text') {
        document.getElementById(fElementId).value = val;
        PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue(id, {value: val});
    }

    else if(objType == 'checkbox') {
        document.getElementById(fElementId).checked = val;
        PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue(id, {value: val});
    }

    else if(objType == 'combobox') {
        document.getElementById(fElementId).selectedIndex = val;
        var sLabel = document.getElementById(fElementId).options[document.getElementById(fElementId).selectedIndex].label;
        PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.annotationStorage.setValue(id, {value: sLabel});
    }

}
```